# Mysql - Return rows that have no associated records in another table plus max that do have records

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

A simplified version of my problem. I have 2 tables:

Scores:

```
id  code_id score
1   11     100
2   12     20
3   13     40
4   14     70
5   15     90
6   16     10
7   17     30
8   18     50
```

Codes:

```
id   code
11   
12
13
14
15
16    BBB
17    BBB
18    BBB
```

I need to produce a Mysql SELECT query that would return all the rows from the Scores table that have no associated codes in the Codes table plus just the highest score from rows that do have identical codes in the Codes table.

The required output is show below. Score ID's 1-5 are present as they have no associated code but only ID 8 is selected because it is the highest value of all the scores with a BBB code.

```
id  code_id score
1   11     100
2   12     20
3   13     40
4   14     70
5   15     90
8   18     50
```

I hope that makes sense. I thought this would be an easy one but It has me puzzled. I have checked out a load of the [greatest-n-per-group] tagged questions and most seem to only reference one table when performing GROUP BYs and subselects and have not helped.

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you really have code records of 11-15 with no code value?  in this case that data is making this more complicated.  Without that data this might be easier to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something with your requirements but it might be easier to use a UNION ALL between two queries.

To get the rows that have a `null` code in the `codes` table you can use:

```
select s.id, s.code_id, s.score
from scores s
where exists (select id
              from codes c
              where s.code_id = c.id
                and c.code is null)
```

Then to get the `max(score)` for each `code`, you can use:

```
select s.id, s.code_id, s.score
from scores s
inner join codes c
  on s.code_id = c.id
inner join
(
  select c.code, max(s.score) score
  from scores s
  inner join codes c
    on s.code_id = c.id
  where c.code is not null
  group by c.code
) m
  on c.code = m.code
  and s.score = m.score;
```

Finally you can use a UNION ALL to combined the two queries:

```
select s.id, s.code_id, s.score
from scores s
where exists (select id
              from codes c
              where s.code_id = c.id
                and c.code is null)
union all
select s.id, s.code_id, s.score
from scores s
inner join codes c
  on s.code_id = c.id
inner join
(
  select c.code, max(s.score) score
  from scores s
  inner join codes c
    on s.code_id = c.id
  where c.code is not null
  group by c.code
) m
  on c.code = m.code
  and s.score = m.score
  group by c.code //To remove duplicates where the code and the score are equal
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/cbaef/1).

Edit as a side note if the `code` value is an empty string and not `null`, then you can alter the code to use `''` (see [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26a95/5)).

Comment: Many thanks for that detailed prompt response bluefeet I will put it to the test in the morning. Looks hopeful ;-)

Comment: @Termine You are welcome, let me know if there are any issues. :)

Comment: Sorry bluefeet. I didn't make myself clear enough. ID 8 is shown in my desired results because it has the highest score not because it has the highest ID. I am working in this now and will post if I crack it.

Comment: @Termine oops, that was my mistake. I have updated the query and the demos.

Comment: Thanks @bluefeet. The example works well and has helped me alot. However it fails when the scores are identical as it returns all of them rather just one which is desired. See fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30a39/1. Its all to do with the first row returned by the GROUP BY. Strangely I have my more complex version working but when I apply the same theory to this example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/3ae7f/5 the wrong IDs are displayed??? I have omitted the top part of the union as I get that bit. Hope you can shed some light?

Comment: @Termine If the scores are the same, then which id do you want returned?

Comment: Just 1 result please. I.e. if all BBB's are 10 then just 1 row containing the 10. But I need the IDs of the returned row to be intact.

Comment: To further clarify I need the highest score, but when they are the same I need just one of the rows returned but I always need the code_id of the matched row. Thx...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select s.*
from scores s join
     (select coalesce(code, cast(id as varchar(32))) as codeid, max(id) as id
      from codes c
      group by  coalesce(code, cast(id as varchar(32)))
     ) c
     on s.code_id = c.id;
```

The idea is to summarize the codes table to get the maximum id per code, as well as a single row for each id where the code is NULL.

The following shows the results (apologies, this is for SQL Server but the code would be quite similar there):

```
declare @scores table (id int identity(1, 1), code_id int, score int);

insert into @scores(code_id, score)
    select 11, 100 union all
    select 12, 20 union all
    select 13, 40 union all
    select 14, 70 union all
    select 15, 90 union all
    select 16, 30 union all
    select 17, 30 union all
    select 18, 50;

declare @codes table (id int, code varchar(3));

insert into @codes(id, code)
    select 11, NULL union all
    select 12, NULL union all
    select 13, NULL union all
    select 14, NULL union all
    select 15, NULL union all
    select 16, 'BBB' union all
    select 17, 'BBB' union all
    select 18, 'BBB';   

select s.*
from @scores s join
     (select coalesce(code, cast(id as varchar(32))) as codeid, max(id) as id
      from @codes c
      group by  coalesce(code, cast(id as varchar(32)))
     ) c
     on s.code_id = c.id
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. That doesn't look too Mysql friendly but I will try to make it work if I can't do it with a simpler query.

Comment: @Termine . . . The query itself is standard SQL.  The only issue is the use of a table variable instead of a temporary table for testing.  It should work fine in MySQL on your data.